# Are there any SEO benefits by using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google

Google introduced [Google Tag Manager](http://google.co.in/tagmanager). When following the 4 steps to create it, the keyword and website URL are optional. I created a container without keyword and URL, but it gave me the following script code and said to paste it to all the website pages.  What is the benefit for me?

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript>
    <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-6Q96"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
<script>
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-6Q96');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->"
```

This code is not related to my domain and keyword.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Google Tag Manage FAQ](http://www.google.com/tagmanager/faq.html)

> **What Is a Tag?**
>
> Tags are tiny bits of website code that let you measure traffic and visitor behavior, understand the impact of online advertising and social channels, use remarketing and audience targeting, test and improve your site, and more.

The tags will have no effect on the SEO of a webpage.  They are intended instead as analytics to measure how well advertising is working.